# vector in map in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

```
typedef vector<string>              tdv_Str;
typedef map<string, tdv_Str, CaseI> tdm_StrList; // var name, possible values
typedef map<short, tdm_StrList>     tdm_VarList; // type, var list
```

*`CaseI` is string map sorting with case insensitive.

When I check if the key of `tdm_VarList` (`list`) is existing or not:

```
if (list.count(key) == 0)
// ...
```

then compiled it, I got the following error:

```
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1089): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\map(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<short,tdm_StrList,std::less<short>,std::allocator<std::pair<const short,tdm_StrList>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          Src\APS.cpp(683) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=short,
1>              _Ty=tdm_StrList
1>          ]
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1089): warning C4503: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::_Insert' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<short,tdm_StrList,std::less<short>,std::allocator<std::pair<const short,tdm_StrList>>,false>
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You elevated a warning ("decorated name length exceeded") to an error. 
In other words, the internal name for the complex type you define has become longer than 4096 characters.
The corresponding [MS documentation for the warning message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/074af4b6.aspx) explains the problem inmore detail and suggests work-araounds.

Comment: wow, what an unfortunate consequence of a heavily templated standard library

Comment: @vu1p3n0x no, it's an unfortunate consequence of using a Microsoft product. There are better products for writing c++. The clang compiler is far superior to Microsoft's efforts. The CLion IDE is excellent.